# Protocol Buffers vs XML/JSON for data entry outside of programming effort

Tags: json, xml, protocol-buffers, data-entry

I would love to use protocol buffers, but I am not sure if they fit my use case. Here it is:

I have a Quiz app. This requires a bunch of data, like categories,  questions, a list of answers (and which ones are correct). **I do not want to be responsible for entering this data - I would prefer to pass it off to a non-programmer to serialize all this data for me**, in either XML or JSON. Then my app would just read in the data file.

Does Google's Protocol Buffers fit my use case? Or should I stick to a more traditional format like XML or JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think not: Protobuf is a binary format. So then you would need to support a text format like XML or JSON and Protobuf.

Also it does not seem you would benefit from Protobufs better berformance at all.